# How to run custom tool from VS2022 extension?

Tags: vsix, envdte, vs-extensibility, customtool

I'm developing a Visual Studio 2022 extension with the [Visual Studio Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/vsix/visual-studio-community-toolkit?view=vs-2022). The extension modifies some resx files and I'd like to run the associated custom tool to regenerate the corresponding *.Designer.cs file after a resx file is modified.

In another extension for a previous VS version, I was able to do it like this:

```
ProjectItem item = _dte.Solution.FindProjectItem(filename);
VSProjectItem vSProjectItem = item?.Object as VSProjectItem;
vSProjectItem?.RunCustomTool();
```

With `_dte` being of type `EnvDTE._DTE`. However now I can't find a way to get that _dte object. All I have is an static `VS` that provides some basic features as the ones described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/vsix/tips/files?view=vs-2022

However, I can't find there anything related to running a file's custom tool.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I'm trying to do exactly the same thing.

Comment: No, I didn't find anything.